# Windows 7 printer sharing without homegroups?

Tags: windows, homegroup

Me and my sibling have windows 7 computers. I set up a homegroup and one the other computer it shows that I created a homegroup and asks for the password.

I've tried various times to change the password, create a new homegroup, etc, but after a couple minutes of the loading bar, all it says is "Homegroup encountered an error"

Are there any realistic ways to share printers with Windows 7?

edit: Appears that the problem is likely caused by the network bridge connecting my other device to the internet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - make sure printer/file sharing is enabled on both (In Windows 7, you can do this from network and sharing centre then click on advanced sharing settings, or make sure the zone is set to home).

Next, go to the computer that has the printer plugged in to it and go to devices and printers, right click and go to sharing, then enable sharing and give it a name.

Go to the other computer and type `\\computername` or `\\computer_ip_address`. You should see the printer - simply double click to add and you are done.

... Rushing and about to leave for work, if you need more help/want screenshots, let me know and I will do it a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 users not in a HomeGroup: You may also have to go to Network Sharing > Change advanced sharing settings > Under all networks, select Turn off password protected sharing

Everything should work for you then.